# How to import the data from a partitioned table to an in-memory table?

Tags: sql-insert, dolphindb, data-import

Suppose there is an empty in-memory table t whose columns are the same as a partitioned table, how to import the data from the partitioned table to t.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the following SQL statement to query the specified data in the partitioned table. If the data volume is large, loop over the table partition by partition for query.

```
data=select * from loadTable(...) where partition(...)
```

Second, import the data into the in-memory table t using the `tableInsert` function, which can return the number of inserted rows. Then, set the variable data to NULL to release it.

tableInsert(t, data)
data=NULL
You can also use the `mr` function to import the data in parallel by partition, or use the `replay` function to directly replay the data to the in-memory table.